# How to sync PDF reading progress in Okular between several computers?

Tags: 22.04, pdf, sync, okular, ebooks

I have several computers where my books and documents are stored in identical file structure. I sync these books with Dropbox (at most the parent folder where Dropbox is located is different, but I can try to make its name the same, if necessary).

I use Okular to read documents. Okular remembers the last page I read.

Is there any way to sync particular Okular config files so that it remembers the page I last read across computers?

Comment: Here is a similar question about Foliate Ebook reader. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1486289/how-to-sync-reading-progress-in-foliate-ebook-reader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okular [saves information](https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/where-does-okular-save-the-last-read-page-of-pdf-files/45646/2?u=archisman) about the last read page in `~/.local/share/okular/docdata`.

We want to sync this directory. I will use MEGAsync, but you are free to choose your favorite cloud storage service.

Create a new directory `okular_docdata` inside MEGAsync directory, and symlink them.

(*Of course, you can set the name and location of the symlinked directory according to your preference*.)

```
cd /path/to/MEGAsync
mkdir okular_docdata
mv ~/.local/share/okular /path/to/MEGAsync/okular_docdata/
ln -s /path/to/MEGAsync/okular_docdata/ /home/username/.local/share/okular
```

Repeat the same in all the computers.

Afterwards, your reading progress will be synced when you run the MEGAsync desktop client.