# How to sync epub reading progress in Foliate ebook reader across different computers?

Tags: sync, ebooks, foliate

I use Foliate ebook reader to read epubs. My books are stored in the same directory structure across different computers (including same partition mount point). I want to sync my reading progress. How to do that?

Comment: Here is a similar question about Okular https://askubuntu.com/questions/1481787/how-to-sync-reading-progress-in-okular-between-several-computers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using MEGAsync to sync my reading progress. But you can modify the method appropriately to use another sync client.

I created a directory `foliate_progress` in MEGA.

Then, I moved `~/.local/share/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate` to `/path/to/MEGAsync/foliate_progress`.

```
mv ~/.local/share/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate  /path/to/MEGAsync/foliate_progress/
```

I ran the MEGAsync client to sync it.

Finally I symlinked this folder back to its original location.

```
ln -s  /path/to/MEGAsync/foliate_progress/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate /home/username/.local/share/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate
```

Do this in all your computers. Afterwards, run MEGA to sync the progress.